# Is the velocity of time ultimately dependent on 'manas' alone?

Tags: yoga, time, lokas

It is well-known that different lokas have different velocities of time. [For example](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b058.htm)

> 1. A month of human beings is equal to a day and night of the Pitris.
> 2. A year (of human beings) is equal to a day and night of the gods.
> 3. 8.6 Billion Years or 2 Kalpas of human beings is equal to one day and night of Brahma.

I want to know the core entity that is responsible for the experience of *velocity* of the time. I am not saying that Loka is not responsible, but want to know the subtlest entity possible. Obviously, Loka is not the answer as manas is responsible for the experience of Loka. It is evident that manas is alone responsible for the experience of the existence of time.  But this question is on the velocities of time rather than existence.

Some yogis can experience different velocities of time even though they are humans. Normal humans also experience different velocities of time in dreams or sometimes based on their mood and involvement with their events. No one experiences time in sushupthi as manas becomes inactive. So, it seems that manas is also the sole responsibility for the different velocities of time.

Am I true? Is manas/Chitta alone ultimately responsible for the experience of different velocities of time? Please provide an answer from scriptures other than Yoga Vasishta.

Comment: Good question. Good thinking on connecting the subtle aspect of creation

Comment: In north pole, it is light for 6 months and dark for 6 months. if you consider light as day time and dark as night time, then from perspective of someone living in north pole, their 1 full day is equal to 1 day-time + 1 night-time = 1 year of humans. so, it's not just manas responsible for velocity. we know time only because of passage of events. if nothing changed, and no event happened, we don't know that "time passed". this means, the more events/changes that happen, the more time feels like going fast. For other lokas, things don't change that often, so time goes slowly.